# Nested Loop across a horizontal database in excel

Tags: vba, excel

[image]Hi there I have a database which has 91 columns, and each column has rows from  row 8 to 21 (fixed) . The 91 columns contain department headers and the row content is dependent on the department header. The columns go in an alternate manner whereby dept 1 is in column C , dept 2 in column E and it follows the patter for all 91 columns. I want to do an automation for the given formula `"=SUMIFS('L4 - Data Sheet'!$Q:$Q,'L4 - Data Sheet'!$R:$R,'WF - L4'!BY$5,'L4 - Data Sheet'!$P:$P,$A8,'L4 - Data Sheet'!$A:$A,'WF - L4'!$A$3)"` using nested loop but it does not seem to work, neither do I have a clear idea on how i can go about it. Because hard coding 91 dept column cells with the respective row range of each column is a very tedious job:/ This is my current working hard code I did .

```
Sub WFCorp4()
    With Sheets("WF - L4 (2)") '91 columns * 2  because there is two different subsectors qty and direct assigned space
        '.Range("BY8:BY21").Formula = "=SUMIFS('L4 - Data Sheet'!$Q:$Q,'L4 - Data Sheet'!$R:$R,'WF - L4'!BY$5,'L4 - Data Sheet'!$P:$P,$A8,'L4 - Data Sheet'!$A:$A,'WF - L4'!$A$3)"
        '.Range("CA8:CA21").Formula = "=SUMIFS('L4 - Data Sheet'!$Q:$Q,'L4 - Data Sheet'!$R:$R,'WF - L4'!CA$5,'L4 - Data Sheet'!$P:$P,$A8,'L4 - Data Sheet'!$A:$A,'WF - L4'!$A$3)"
        '.Range("CN8:CN21").Formula = "=SUMIFS('L4 - Data Sheet'!$U:$U,'L4 - Data Sheet'!$R:$R,'WF - L4'!CM$5,'L4 - Data Sheet'!$P:$P,$A8,'L4 - Data Sheet'!$A:$A,'WF - L4'!$A$3)"
    End With
End Sub
```

This is the nested loop code i tried for the worksheet.

```
Sub ShortcutWFCorp4()

Dim lastcol As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
lastcol = Cells(8, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
lastrow = Cells(21, "C").End(xlUp).Row
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long


For i = i + 2 To lastcol

    For j = 8 To lastrow

  Sheets("WF - L4 (2)").Cells(i, j).Range.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS('L4 - Data Sheet'!R4C17:R132C17,'L4 - Data Sheet'!R4C18:R132C18,'WF - L4 (2)'!i,'L4 - Data Sheet'!R4C16:R132C16,'L4 - Data Sheet'R4C1,R132C1,'WF - L4(2)'!R3C1)"


Next

Next

End Sub
```

Would appreciate if someone could help! Thanks

Attached is the image of how it roughly looks like. Each cell has that formula stated in my question . I want to automate with the use of nested loop to tabulate the outputs in the qty column! And the depts go in an alternative order.

Comment: Your outer For statement should be `For i = 3 to lastcol step 2`

Comment: but will it jump alternatively? Because the columns are in 3,5,7 etc... @OldUgly

Comment: `For i = 3 to lastcol Step 2` will cause i to be `3,5,7,...`. If `Step` is omitted, the increments are 1.

Comment: If you could post a redacted version of your input and expected output, this could be easily solved.

Comment: Refer to my edit! @OldUgly

Comment: Your SUMIFS is badly malformed. You've stuck *i* arbitrarily in the middle without concatenating it in and there are an uneven number of criteria_range/criteria pairs. Get the formula working in one cell on the worksheet and add it to your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I deciphered your formula from the one you supplied. The nested loop is unnecessary with a well designed formula; simply put it into all cells at once like a Fill Down.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ShortcutWFCorp4()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    'cannot use lastrow until there is something in column C
    Dim lastCol As Long ', lastRow As Long

    With Worksheets("WF - L4 (2)")  '<~~ define it ONCE here
        'you want to put formulas into all the columns with QTY in row 7
        lastCol = .Cells(7, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        'I guess column C is the left-most in your image but you canot
        'get last row list this until there is something in it
        'I'll use 21
        'lastrow = .Cells(21, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        'columns 3, 5, 7, etc
        For i = 3 To lastCol Step 2
            '"=SUMIFS('L4 - Data Sheet'!$Q:$Q,
            '         'L4 - Data Sheet'!$R:$R, 'WF - L4'!BY$5,
            '         'L4 - Data Sheet'!$P:$P, $A8,
            '         'L4 - Data Sheet'!$A:$A, 'WF - L4'!$A$3)
            .Range(.Cells(8, i), .Cells(21, i)).FormulaR1C1 = _
                        "=SUMIFS('L4 - Data Sheet'!C17, " & _
                                "'L4 - Data Sheet'!C18, R5C" & 74 + i & ", " & _
                                "'L4 - Data Sheet'!C16, RC1, " & _
                                "'L4 - Data Sheet'!C1, R3C1)"
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

I guessed that the first **Qty** was in C7. You stated that the formulas were to go into rows 8-21. If there isn't something in column C down to row 21 then looking for the 'last row' didn't make sense so I hard-coded rows 8 to 21 in.

Comment: hi what does this portion of the code mean? & 74 + i & ", " & _

Comment: figured it !Thanks a tonne.